# Crontab nothing happens?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, cron

If I run

```
crontab -l
16 12 * * *  cd ~/web/im2txt/im2txt && ./train.sh
```

I have also tried

```
cd ~/web/im2txt/im2txt && ./train.sh
```

It works.

I'm waiting till my osx system-clock is 16:12 (I set it up at 16:11) I have tried it with the terminal open and closed. Nothing happens, no error no nothing. The shell-command outputs data to the terminal when you run it normally.

What Can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are scheduling the command for 12:16 :)

When you run `sudo crontab -e`, you can see the following comment right before where you are supposed to write:

```
# m h dom mon dow  command
```

That means minutes first, then hours. Maybe try:

```
12 16 * * * <command>
```

Finally could simpify the command doing the following:

```
/home/<your username>/web/im2txt/im2txt/train.sh
```

***TL;DR:***

```
12 16 * * * /home/<your username>/web/im2txt/im2txt/train.sh
```